# Array Slice to create new array

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I assign a slice of an array to a new array. I am trying to assign the maximal consecutive of equal elements to a new array.

I think I have the  basic logic right but cannot slice to a new array. This is exercise 4 in Arrays -  Fundamentals of computer programming with c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class ArrayEx4
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] testArray = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 }; // Output wanted {2,2,2};

        int count = 0;
        int bestCount = 0;
        int startArray = 0;
        int endArray = 0;
        int first = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < testArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (testArray[i] == testArray[i+1])
            {
                count += 1;
                i = first;
                if (count > bestCount)
                {
                    count = bestCount;
                    startArray = first;
                    endArray = first + bestCount;
                }
            }
            int[] bestArray = testArray.Slice(startArray, endArray);
            Console.WriteLine("The best array is  {0}", bestArray);
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting a directive error so I added using System.Collections.Generic; but I am still getting this error.

```
C:\Users\Sayth\Documents\Scripts>csc ArrayEx4.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.33440
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

ArrayEx4.cs(28,32): error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition
        for 'Slice' and no extension method 'Slice' accepting a first argument
        of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive
        or an assembly reference?)
```

**EDIT**

The logic in my solution above never worked. Here is the updated code  including answer below as working.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Arr4
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] testArray = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 }; // Output wanted {2,2,2};
        int count = 0;
        int bestCount = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int a = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < testArray.Length -1; i++)
        {
            while (testArray[i] == testArray[a])
            {
                count += 1;
                a += 1;
                if (count > bestCount)
                {
                    start = i;
                    bestCount = count;
                }
            }
        }

     int end = bestCount + start;
     Console.WriteLine("The start is {0} and count is {1}", start, bestCount);
     var bestArray = testArray.Skip(start)
                      .Take(end - start)
                      .ToArray();
        Console.Write("{ ");
        Console.Write(string.Join(", ", bestArray));
        Console.Write(" }");
    }   

}
```

Comment: The .Net `Array` class has no method named `Slice`, as the compiler is telling you, the closest to what you're trying for is `Array.Copy` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx, or a combination of `Skip` and `Take`, as in @BrokenGlass's answer.

Comment: Check out ArraySlice<T> which allows you to use a section of an array without copying: https://github.com/henon/SliceAndDice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Linq you could do this:

```
var bestArray = testArray.Skip(startArray) 
                         .Take(endArray - startArray)
                         .ToArray();
```

(Don't forget to add `using System.Linq`)

Comment: `I am trying to assign the maximal consecutive of equal elements to a new array` How does it answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

In c#, you don't need to loop through the array manually, you can just use LINQ.

This will get the job done for you :)

```
int[] testArray = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 }; // Output wanted {2,2,2};

int[] maxSequence = testArray.Select((n, i) => new { Value = n, Index = i})
    .OrderBy(s => s.Value)
    .Select((o, i) => new { Value = o.Value, Diff = i - o.Index } )
    .GroupBy(s => new { s.Value, s.Diff})
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .First()
    .Select(f => f.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with **C# 8.0** you can use [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range) class to make array slice.

```cs
int[] testArray = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
int[] output = testArray[4..7]; // {2, 2, 2} // Note that end of range (7) is exclusive
```

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges) for details